# Custom React Helmet cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, types, react-helmet

I forked the React-Helmet repo (https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

So I have my custom component:

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-custom';
```

When I use it in a Typescript file I got this error:

```
ERROR in /home/xxxxx/Documents/xxxxx/website-xxxxx/src/pages/homepage/HomeHelmet.tsx
./src/pages/homepage/HomeHelmet.tsx 77:3-9
[tsl] ERROR in /home/xxxxx/Documents/xxxxx/website-xxxxx/src/pages/homepage/HomeHelmet.tsx(77,4)
      TS2786: 'Helmet' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'HelmetWrapper' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'HelmetWrapper' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.
```

I installed the types:

```
npm install --save @types/react-helmet
```

The problem is that these types are not visible by my custom component. So I cannot use it in a Typescript file.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, but from within an Azure Static Web App build pipeline. From reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567388/custom-react-helmet-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component), it appears this is a problem related to React 18, Typescript and Helmet.

From the referenced thread, the solution that worked for me was to:

1. uninstall @types/react-helmet
2. add a file `helmet.d.ts`, with the contents:
   `declare module "react-helmet";`

Once I did that, the build completed successfully.

The other solution from the thread, which I didn't need, but would have been my last resort, was to add `{/* @ts-ignore */}` to the JSX right before the opening tag for the `<Helmet />`.